# How is it possible that the HorizontalAdvance of a glyph is smaller than the glyph's width?

Tags: fonts, freetype, glyph, freetype2

I work with SharpFont, a C# FreeType library.
After loading a Times New Roman OpenType file, I get the metrics of all glyphs.
I noticed that the HorizontalAdvance of the chars 'f', 'w', 'y', 'A', '/', '\' is smaller than their normal width and the VerticalAdvance of the char '@' is smaller than its height. How is this possible? I always thought that the HorizontalAdvance is the width plus some padding (bearingX).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding horizontal advance, this is quite normal. Numerous factors can dictate the spacing of characters in a font file, and the advance width is only the simplest and crudest, intended to work in a majority of situations. For instance, an *f* has an advance width a little wider than its crossbar, because it most commonly comes before lowercase letters like *a*, *e* and *r*. Its curved ascender may overshoot that width and hang over into the next character's space. This is only a problem when you get a tall character like *l* or *b* or *T*, and a collision in this case is avoided either by kerning or by creating a ligature.

It is common practice for font designers to determine the advance widths of characters visually, by spacing them between other standard characters. Capitals are usually spaced between capital Os and Hs, like such:

OOOFOOO HHHFHHH

And lowercase characters are spaced between lowercase os and ns:

ooofooo nnnfnnn

These are adjusted carefully to 'look' well balanced. Then kerning deals with problem situations of too much or too little space between character pairs. Characters like *f*, *v*, *w*, *y*, *A*, *V*, *W*, *Y*, */* often end up overshooting their advance width, because that's what's required to make the spacing look right.

Regarding the vertical advance of *@*, this may be in error. Vertical advance is used for CJK scripts and others such as traditional Mongolian where the characters are to be read vertically downwards, not horizontally. Vertical advance may have been included here accidentally, or it may be not properly tested for use in e.g. vertical Chinese writing. Or it may be that it only slightly extends into the space above and below, and that was deemed not to be a problem.